# Check in JavaScript if all number elements in an array are adequate

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array defined like this:

```
var numbers = [11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18];
```

I want to check if all numbers in this array are greater 10 and I only want a single output.

I tried this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
     if (numbers[i] > 10) {
         console.log("Valid");
     } else {
         console.log("Not valid");
     }
}
```

This gives me multiple outputs, since it is inside the loop, but I just want a single valid statement.

PS: Sorry about this noob question.

Comment: just have a single if like if(numbers[i] < 10) {console.log("invalid"); break;}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I personally prefer `Array.prototype.every()`.

This function executes a provided callback once for each element until the callback returns `false`. If this happens, the `every()` function will return `false`.

Here is an example:

```js
var numbers = [11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18];

function checkElements(element, index, array) {
  return (element > 10);
}

if (numbers.every(checkElements)) console.log('Valid');
else console.log('Not valid');
```

Read more about the [every() function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every).

Comment: Thank you! That did it for me!

Answer (score 4):

There are a number of solutions to this problem. The simplest of which is probably to create a function:

```
var numbers = [11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18];

function allNumbersLessThan10() {
  for (var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
    if (numbers[i] > 10) {

      return false
    }
  }

  return true;
}

console.log(allNumbersLessThan10());
```

If any number is greater than 10, then all numbers cannot be less than 10, and so we return `false`.

If we finish evaluating all the numbers in the loop and we have not yet find one who is greater than ten, then all numbers must be less than 10, and so we return `true`.

Comment: This will exit the function as soon as the first valid item will be hit... Sure there will be only one output, but it will be wrong.

Comment: Thanks :-) it seems from other answers that there are already built-in functions doing exactly this though. I must admit I didn't know of them...

Answer (score 4):

Right in the documentation for [`some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

```
function isBiggerThan10(element, index, array) {
  return element > 10;
}
[2, 5, 8, 1, 4].some(isBiggerThan10);  // false
```

so in your case you need to reverse that logic.

```
function isSmallerThan10(element, index, array) {
  return element < 10;
}
[2, 5, 8, 1, 4].some(isSmallerThan10);  //true
```

---

Other option is to use [`every()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every)

```
function isBigEnough(element, index, array) {
  return element >= 10;
}
[12, 5, 8, 130, 44].every(isBigEnough);   // false
[12, 54, 18, 130, 44].every(isBigEnough); // true
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this one:

```
numbers=["11","12","13","14","15","16","17","18"];

 if (numbers[0] > 10 && numbers[1] >10 && numbers[2] > 10 && numbers[3] >10 && numbers[4] > 10 && numbers[5] >10 && numbers[6] > 10 && numbers[7] >10) {
     console.log("Valid");
 } else {
     console.log("Not valid");
 }
```

It is without the for iteration,if it is used in a bad way can damage the life of the device.

Comment: _"If it is used in a bad way can damage the life of the device"_ I'm sorry, but this statement is utter rubbish...

Comment: No problem.What's the problem?

Comment: "_can damage the life of the device_" please prove it. I'm seriously interested.